# Is there ever a reason not to take the completion of a measure space?

Tags: measure-theory

It seems to me like whenever we have a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$, it's pretty much always more convenient to work with $(X, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the completion, i.e.
$$\mathcal{X} = \left\{ A \cup E : A \in \mathcal{A} \land \exists N \in \mathcal{A} \; \left( E \subseteq N \land \mu(N) = 0 \right) \right\} .$$
This has several advantages, e.g. if two functions agree almost everywhere, and one is measurable, then so is the other. Wikipedia also mentions that [Maharam's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharam%27s_theorem) applies to complete measure spaces, as well as for other classes of measure spaces, but doesn't mention general measure spaces.

But is there ever a reason why we'd specifically want to stick to $\mathcal{A}$ without making the passage to $\mathcal{X}$?

Hopefully this isn't too broad or subjective a question.

Comment: I would rather ask the opposite question: is there ever a good reason to complete measures?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I list a handful in the original post. It can also be nice to say that a subset of a null set is null.

Comment: None of these reasons is compelling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When we pass to the completion, we lose information about the *definability* of our constructions! For concreteness, I'll work with borel sets (which get completed to the lebesgue measurable sets) for this answer.

When mathematicians show that things exist, oftentimes they're pathological (for instance, they might be built using the axiom of choice). This is good, because it tells us that something exists, but it's unsatisfying because it means we can't actually *look at it* in the sense that there's no actual definition you can write down to really get your hands on the thing you've built. Depending on your taste, this might be aesthetically offputting, but it can also have real consequences if you want to make computations with the thing you've built. It's much easier to do things when you have a concrete description of your object!

Through this lens, asking for your construction to be *measurable* is one way of ensuring that there's a "concrete way" to describe your object. This tells you that it isn't too pathological. Indeed, there's lots of theorems that say that your construction must be "better behaved" if it's measurable
(this is part of a more general pattern in mathematics, which you can read about at an [old blog post](https://grossack.site/2021/09/07/examples-of-sns-theorems.html) of mine).

But what's the difference between asking for borel vs lebesgue measurability?

Borel measurability should be thought of as honest definability. You have to actually have a way to describe your set (in at most countably many steps) from basic "known" constructions (the open sets). This tells us how to concretely get our hands on the object we've constructed!
Lebesgue measurability, though, is more complicated. We've thrown in the subsets of every nullset, and we *don't have any control* over what those look like! So in the lebesgue world we're allowed to do something "undefinable" (read: use the axiom of choice, etc.) as long as we ensure that we only do it on a set of measure $0$.

In summary, borel measurability tells us that our object is definable in some strong sense, which tells us that our object has to be "nice" in some sense. Lebesgue measurability tells us that our object is "almost everywhere" definable, but we're allowed to sweep a little bit of undefinability under the nullset rug.

I'm struggling to think of an example that's relevant to "mainstream" mathematics right now, but one way to see that borel sets are qualitatively nicer than arbitary lebesgue measurable sets is this: Every borel set has the [perfect set property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property), so a borel set cannot be a counterexample to the continuum hypothesis (if a counterexample exists). However it's entirely possible for a set that's merely *lebesgue* measurable to be a counterexample to CH! (Can you see how?)

If you want to learn more about this, and to see in practice how borel vs lebesgue measurability is meaningful, I suggest looking into [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). In particular, the exciting and trendy area of [descriptive combinatorics](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/O.Pikhurko/TCC/index.html), which is where we care about more than just *solving* some combinatorial problem. We want to solve it in a *definable way* so that we can actually *use* the solution!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Thank you very much. As a student, I have always had this feeling that "Borel measurable" is more constructive than "Lebesgue measurable", but I could never understand why, exactly. In many fields of analysis you don't really appreciate the difference, so I forgot about this old curiosity of mine until your answer. Thanks!